# Java, how do I create a hash map outside of main but refer to it in main or another method

Tags: java

> Java, how do I create a hash map outside of main but refer to it in main or another method
>   import java.util.*;

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;

// Create a hash map 

        HashMap<String, Double> hm = new HashMap<String, Double>();

// Put elements into the map

        hm.put("John Doe", new Double(3434.34)); 
        hm.put("Tom Smith", new Double(123.22)); 
        hm.put("Jane Baker", new Double(1378.00)); 
        hm.put("Todd Hall", new Double(99.22)); 
        hm.put("Ralph Smith", new Double(-19.08));

class HashMapDemo 
{ 

    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        // Get a set of the entries

        Set<Entry< String, Double> > set = hm.entrySet();

        // Get an iterator

        Iterator<Entry< String, Double> > i = set.iterator();

        // Display elements

        while(i.hasNext())
        { 
            Entry< String, Double > me = i.next(); 
            System.out.print( me.getKey() + ": " ); 
            System.out.println( me.getValue() ); 
        }

        System.out.println();

        // Deposit 1000 into John Doe's account

        double balance = hm.get( "John Doe" ).doubleValue(); 
        hm.put( "John Doe", new Double(balance + 1000) ); 
        System.out.println( "John Doe's new balance: " + hm.get("John Doe"));

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access an instance value from your static main. To fix this just make your HashMap static.

```
static HashMap<String, Double> hm = new HashMap<String, Double>();

static {
    hm.put("John Doe", new Double(3434.34)); 
    hm.put("Tom Smith", new Double(123.22)); 
    hm.put("Jane Baker", new Double(1378.00)); 
    hm.put("Todd Hall", new Double(99.22)); 
    hm.put("Ralph Smith", new Double(-19.08));
}
```

Now this line will have access to `hm`

```
Set<Entry< String, Double> > set = hm.entrySet();
```

Comment: Good to know. You can accept an answer so others will know you have found a solution http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Glitch but alternatively you can create a class that sets up your hash map and that has a function `getHM()` which returns it. Then in your main you just need to create:

- an object of that class, e.g.

  `Test test = new Test();`
- a new HashMap and assign it the value of getHM(), e.g.

  `HashMap<String, Double> hm = test.getHM();`

and this would be your class Test

```
public class Test {
    HashMap<String, Double> hm;

    public Test() {
        hm = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        hm.put("John Doe", new Double(3434.34)); 
        hm.put("Tom Smith", new Double(123.22)); 
        hm.put("Jane Baker", new Double(1378.00)); 
        hm.put("Todd Hall", new Double(99.22)); 
        hm.put("Ralph Smith", new Double(-19.08));
    }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getHM() {
        return hm;
    }
}
```

I would say that the choice of the solution depends on your requirements BUT if that was your only problem, then the solution given by glitch is probably the easiest/best.

Using the static keyword allows you to retrieve the HashMap without having to create an instance of any object. I believe that this is better in terms of memory usage (but I am no expert in optimization...).

Comment: +1 for good alternative solution. When you are showing code watch when you are mixing spaces and tabs which is what gave you the weird formatting.

Comment: Thank you very much @PLB.  I may use your solution as I continue to develop my program.

Comment: @Glitch thanks for help in formatting. only my second day here, still a lot to learn!